# Meteor.js is constantly running SIGKILL?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, console, debian

When I run my meteor.js project it works fine until I:

A: run meteor mongo

or

B: try to connect to my project through localhost (3000)

after I get the error:

```
=> Exited From Signal: SIGKILL
Killed
```

Sometimes it will randomly run SIGKILL for no reason!
Anybody Know why its doing this?

It was fine until the update (Meteor 0.9.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you're out of memory, use "dmesg" for more information.

Comment: Use `dmesg` where exactly?

Comment: I know this is very far in the past but I found it today and used it. dmesg should be typed in the console where you execute meteor, usually a unix like terminal.